# In-App Purchase Products not showing in iOS 5.1

Tags: ios5, ios4, in-app-purchase

If I use 4.2 iOS device such as 2nd gen iPod touch, products show up.

if I use 5.1 iOS device such as iPhone 4s, no product(s) shows up.

Anybody having same issue?  I'm testing this in the sandbox environment.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3):

The in-app purchase sandbox is so temperamental. If your code is working on 4.2 and not on 5.1 then the problem is probably one of your environment - there is a long list of things that can go wrong.

This guide was the best help I found on the net around in app purchases and highlights the problems with the API and testing:

http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/

The #1 problems I had were:

1. Not signing into the right iTunes sandbox account on the testing device. Always check.
2. Deleting the app off the device, clean build, reinstall. This was very important.
3. Check your in-app purchase codes are right.
4. Interpreting a failure as something wrong with my app. Sometimes a failure meant that the sandbox wasn't responding (cannot connect to itunes store). I would run the same code the next day and it would work. The sandbox doesn't give enough error information for you to know if the sandbox failed or your app code or some mismatch with in-app code data. Put as much debugging log statements in your code to check the response from the server and whether product codes are returned on initialization.

Good luck - it is a very irritating developer experience

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice.  I did check all those but sitll strangely, my products won't show up in my iPhone 4s while they are all shows up fine in iPod 2nd Gen.  I was able to purchase and all that stuff via test users.  Oh well, I will keep work at it to see if I can spot anything wrong.  I guess putting more debug messages in the code will help.  Thanks alot!

Comment: I restarted my macbook air, then clean build and reinstall fixed the issue.  Thanks you.

Comment: +1 for ___"Deleting the app off the device, clean build, reinstall. This was very important"___. Thank you @Narbs!